# Integrating PayPal into an eCommerce platform using JS

Tags: javascript, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

When I try to test payments, my code works only if I use an account of type 'partner' (the account provided when I created the REST API app). However, if I use an account from the testing tools, the payment fails.

This is my code:

```js
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        // Seller information with amount and email
        const sellers = [
            { amount: '2', email: 'sb-eygd426985631@business.example.com' },
            { amount: '2', email: 'sb-g6fky26639079@business.example.com' },
            { amount: '2', email: 'sb-eygd426985631@business.example.com' }
        ];

        // Prepare an array of purchase units for each seller
        const purchase_units = sellers.map((seller, index) => {
            return {
                reference_id: `seller_${index + 1}`, // Unique reference ID for each purchase unit
                amount: {
                    value: seller.amount
                },
                payee: {
                    email_address: seller.email
                }
            };
        });

        // Create the order with the array of purchase units
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: purchase_units
        });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            alert("Payment succeeded");
        });
    },
    onCancel: function(data) {
        alert("Payment canceled.");
    },
    onError: function(err) {
        alert("An error occurred. Please try again later.");
        console.error(err);
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

If I replace the three emails in the array with the email of a partner account, the payment succeeds. However, if I use another account, it tells me: "An error occurred. Please try again later."